# Function that is bounded above by an integral expression is identically zero

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, functional-inequalities

Question: Let $\phi(t)$ be a positive continuous function on $[0, \infty)$ and $f(t,x)$ be continuous function of two variables so that $|f(t,x)| \leq \phi(t) |x|$. Suppose $\int_0^\infty \phi(t) < \infty.$ Show that if the function $y$ satisfies the inequality
$$|y(t)| \leq \int_0^t |f(s, y(s))| \, ds,$$ for all $t \in [0, \infty)$. Then, $y(t) \equiv 0$.

My attempt: If $y$ is a measurable function defined on $[0, \infty)$, let $\mu$ be a finite positive measure defined on $[0, \infty)$ so that $\mu(E) := \int_E \phi $ for every measurable $E \subset [0, \infty)$. Then, by hypothesis we have the following inequality
$$|y(t)| \leq \int_0^t |y(s)|\, d \mu(s)$$
However, I am stuck as I'm not sure how to use the fact that $f$ is continuous function. Any hints/solutions are appreciated.

Comment: For continuous $y$ this is just an application of Grönwall's lemma, but I'm guessing there are no assumptions on $y$ here besides measurable?

Comment: @BrunoB I see thank you for the hints!

Comment: There is apparently [a more general version of Grönwall's lemma for measurable functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality#Integral_form_with_locally_finite_measures) which I just learned exists thanks to your question, but I doubt whoever asked you the question would require the full force of the theorem (unless it's presented before this exercise I guess), there's most likely a way to get your result in a much simpler fashion...